# Sample Split for Cross validation

Tags: cross-validation

I want to split a sample to create a multiple regression model using training dataset.

Problem is, I have three dependent variables (numberA, numberB, numberC) and want to do three regression models. Can I split the sample just once into training and validation dataset and reuse same training dataset generated to create models for dependent variable numberA and numberB? Or must I separately split the original dataset 3 times?

To be honest sample splitting is still a fuzzy concept for me. Thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @JordanLee. [stats.SE] is a site for questions about *statistics*, not how to use statistical software. I think you have a real statistical question here, but you may want to be careful about the way it's framed so that people don't try to vote to close this Q.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: As regression coefficients are computed quite fast, I wonder why you not use n-fold cross-validation, aka "leave-one-out"? For this approach, you test the prediction for *every* sample on a model trained with teh remaining samples.

Comment: Concerning the remark by @gung, it should be added that you should also be careful whether you mention the application of your problem. It happens that very interesting statistical problems are closed by moderators, because there is mention of an application and the moderator thinks that the question is about biology/chemistry/phscics/economics and closes the question.